# List of all published site

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

My company is using Umbraco for a project having many nodes, in turn having published and unpublished sites. My requirement is to get a list of all published site across all node in an xslx, csv etc. Is there any way to get this without hitting Umbraco extented APIs?

Can some help?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the Umbraco services, SQL is probably the best solution

The following query returns all hostnames that are linked to published nodes:

```
SELECT domainName
FROM [dbo].[umbracoDomains] as domains
INNER JOIN [dbo].[cmsDocument] as documents 
ON domains.domainRootStructureID = documents.NodeId
WHERE documents.Published = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. But i need the list of published URLs, above solution will return the nodes

Comment: The above query will return the domains (hostnames), isnt that what you are looking for?

Comment: No. i am looking for all published sites not domain

Comment: What do you mean by site?